# Why is 持 in the sentence 这些持反对意见的员工表示，……?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a short news article about Microsoft's internal attitude towards a Tiktok purchase, wherein there is this sentence:

> 这些**持**反对意见的员工表示，这可能是他们入职微软以来首次怀疑公司采取措施的正确性。
> <sub>[微软六成员工反对收购TikTok 支持盖茨想法](http://news.zol.com.cn/750/7501176.html)，2020年08月11日</sub>

It means something like

> [*My translation*:] These employees with oppositional ideas express [that] this might be the first time since they started employment at Microsoft that they doubt the correctness of the company's adopted measures.

I don't understand why 持 is in this sentence.  It's a bit contradictory since 持 is part of [支持](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%94%AF%E6%8C%81) = "support" while [反对](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8F%8D%E5%AF%B9) = "oppose".

**Question**: Why is 持 in this sentence?

Comment: 持 also means 抱有 in dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**持**, here, is shortened form of 持有.

持 has a definition on [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%8C%81) that reads:

> to hold

持有 is defined on [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%8C%81%E6%9C%89) as:

> to hold (passport, views etc)

You, correctly, translated it as *with*, which also works here.

---

Another term that might help you wrap your mind around this term and usage is the word:

**持方**

[CedPane](http://ssb22.user.srcf.net/gradint/cedpane.html) defines it as:

> side (in debate)